# Why can't Interface Builder set a negative multiple for a constraint, even though [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:] can?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an iOS 9 & 10 app which has a little "tray" UIView along the bottom of the window that slides in and out to display (or hide) certain controls. By default the tray is fully displayed ("slide out") so the user can see everything. There is a button on the far right that they can tap to make the tray "slide in" to the left so that the tray is mostly hidden because it's now off-screen to the left. (The right-most 20 points are the "thumb" that the user can tap to slide in/out, so the thumb is the only part of the tray that remains visible when the tray is slid in.)

The way I'd like to do this is to have two different constraints defined via Interface Builder, and I simply toggle them so that only one is active at a time. For example, the two constraints could be:

trayOutConstraint:

> trayView.leading = (superview.leading * 1) + 0  // result == 0

trayInConstraint:

> trayView.leading = (superview.trailing * -1) + 20  // result == -300 (for example)

It turns out that I can create constraint for trayInConstraint programmatically, like so (**edit: expanded to show how I'm disabling the storyboard's default constraint and adding my new constraint**):

```
// Disable the default constraint (in the storyboard)
[[self trayTripOutLeadingConstraint] setActive:NO];

// Create the new constraint (add to an array by itself)
NSLayoutConstraint *newConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:(id)trayView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:(id)[trayView superview] attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:-1 constant:20];
NSArray *newTrayConstraintsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:newConstraint, nil];

// Remove any existing constraints array and use the new one    
[[self view] removeConstraints:[self tripTrayConstraints]];
[self setTripTrayConstraints:newTrayConstraintsArray];
[[self view] addConstraints:newTrayConstraintsArray];
```

But if I try to create it in Interface Builder, I can't set the multiplier to anything other than 1.0. (Typing any other value simply forces it to reset to "1".)

I see in Apple docs https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html :

> You cannot use a nonidentity multiplier (a value other than 1.0) with
>   location attributes.

But why can I create it in code but not IB?

(Unrelated aside that might be useful to someone else: I also wanted to create a constraint where the multiple was 0 but couldn't do that programmatically or in IB. I found that I could work around the inability to use "0.0" as the multiplier by instead using something very small such as 0.000001.)

Comment: how you are assigning new constrain can you show me here ?

Comment: I have edited my question to include the code which creates and assigns the new constraint. But that's not really my question. My question is not how to create code which creates the desired constraint. I already know that, as shown by the code above. Instead, my question is: why can't I assign a value of "-1" for the "multiplier" within Interface Builder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select `"Reverse First And Second Item"` and re-enter the absolute value of the multiplier => This way (by switching first and second item) the multiplier behaves like it is negative.

[image: Reverse First And Second Item]

First Item: View.Leading
Second Item: Superview.Trailing

[image: normal]

First Item: Superview.Trailing
Second Item: View.Leading

[image: reversed]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I think that's not right, because multiplication doesn't give different sign results depending on the order of the arguments. For example: (320 * -1) == (-1 * 320).

Comment: It's not about signs since you have to use positive Multipliers. It's about where the values get applied. Going -320 points to the right is the same as going 320 points to the left. Since you can not go -320 points to the right - you have to change the direction => "Reverse First And Second Item".

Comment: Thanks for the comments, they helped me to find a different solution. When the tray has been slid in, I had been trying to constrain the leading like this: "trayView.leading = (superview.trailing * -1) + 20"  Your comment made me realize that I could use a positive number by controlling the other side of the tray. Namely, I set the trailing instead of the leading! So the solution became "trayView.trailing = (superview.leading * 1) + 20"  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can assign negative values to `leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints simply`. But You can not assign negative values to any multiplier either from code or in Interface builder. If you are adding any negative value in your code as multiplier that it will be considered as +1 by the compiler and you may get the unexpected result. (In your case , you may got the expected result unexpectedly)

Comment: "You can not assign negative values to any multiplier either from code or in Interface builder..." what makes you say that? Is that specified in Apple documentation anywhere?